# change color and shape of div on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I click the div, I'm trying to make the div turn into a green 30x30 circle over a course of 2 seconds. And then 3 seconds after the animation is done running, I want the red area go back to its original state.

With my code so far, I'm able to click the div and change it's size to 30x30 and shape to a circle

Here's my code so far:

```
  #blue-box {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: blue;
    /* transition:background-color .5s ease-in; */
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out, background-color 2s ease 3s;
}



 .box-change {
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: scale(.3, .3);
    -moz-transform: scale(.3, ,.3);
    -o-transform: scale(.3, .3);
    -ms-transform: scale(.3, .3);
        transform: scale(.3, .3);
    }

var box = $('#blue-box');
box.on('click', function(){
    box.toggleClass('box-change');
    if (box.hasClass('box-change'))
        console.log("testing123");
    else
        console.log("testing testing!");

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gatordh7/gxes2ep3/

To the #blue-box div, I tried including: "transition:background-color .5s ease-in", and then setting the background-color to green on the .box-change class I toggled when the div was clicked, but I still can't figure this out.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in this one http://jsfiddle.net/gxes2ep3/3/

```
var box = $('.blue-box');
box.on('click', function(){
    box.toggleClass('box-change');
    if (box.hasClass('box-change'))
        console.log("testing123");
    else
        console.log("testing testing!");

});
```

You were using id for the box, ids have a higher priority than classes. Also, the css background-color was not the same in blue box and in box-change rules. Ans you had a 3s delay for the color